# "in that" or "by that" in the mentioned context?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> A is distinguished from B **in that / by that**, unlike the latter, the
>   former is intentional.

Which one is more idiomatic: "distinguished in that" or "distinguished by that"?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of them is correct or idiomatic.
**in that** means, roughly, "for the reason that".  We use it to introduce a statement that explains something we just said or gives more information.
**by that** means, roughly, "through the action of 'that'" - that is, literally something you're referring to as "that".

After *"A is distinguished from B"* I would expect **by** (because the use of *is distinguished* implies a passive voice sentence) but not "by that".  For example, I might say:

> A is distinguished from B by being intentional.

or

> A is distinguished from B by the fact that A is intentional.

The only time I would use "by that" is like this:

> A is intentional and B is not; they are distinguished by that.  (i.e., "by the existence of that fact")

The way that you use *in that* is to refer to a fact:

> A is different from B *in that* A is intentional.  (i.e., "for the reason of the fact that")

Comment: How to say it if I want to keep the original structure? Should I use "by the fact that" instead of "in that"?

Comment: I think "by the fact that" is a good, idiomatic way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

Question: A is distinguished from B in that / by that, unlike the latter, the former is intentional.

Correction: A is different from B in that, unlike A, it is intentional. [Note: there are other ways of writing this A is different from B in that it is intentional, unlike A]

One thing is different from another; one differs from another.

Distinguish is used slightly different:
He can't distinguish A from B. To distinguish means to tell the difference between two things. **People distinguish one thing from another. Things do not distinguish other things and therefore, one thing is not distinguished from another as given in the question unless a person is involved.**

The passive use of distinguish to mean telling the difference between two things (not with the meaning of "to stand out" as in, "He is a distinguished speaker.") is somewhat heavy.

Man 1 and Man 2 in the line-up of suspects were distinguished by the witness.

Comment: What about "What distinguishes A from B is the fact that, unlike the latter, the former is intentional."